# Fire a (KEY_ENTER) key press event in GWT

Tags: gwt

What I'm trying to do is fire an enter key press event in GWT.
This is my keyhandler:

```
    itemBox.addKeyDownHandler(new KeyDownHandler() { 
          public void onKeyDown(KeyDownEvent event) {
                 if(event.getNativeKeyCode == KeyCodes.KEY_ENTER) {
                       // do something
                 }
```

Then later I wanna fire an enter key press event but I can't seem to figure out how I do this. I wanna do something like KeyDownEvent.setNativeKeyCode(KEY_ENTER).

```
     textBox.fireEvent(new KeyDownEvent(null));
```

Is it possible to set these parameters?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can fire the event using DomEvent.fireNativeEvent, instead of textBox.fireEvent.

Here is a working example how to do this:

```
final TextBox tb = new TextBox();
tb.addKeyDownHandler(new KeyDownHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onKeyDown(KeyDownEvent event) {
     if(event.getNativeKeyCode() == KeyCodes.KEY_ENTER) {
                 Window.alert("enter!");
           }
    }
});

Button b = new Button("keyevent");
b.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
    DomEvent.fireNativeEvent(Document.get().createKeyDownEvent(false, false, false, false, KeyCodes.KEY_ENTER), tb);
    }
});

RootPanel.get().add(tb);
RootPanel.get().add(b);
```